# Shortcut key for bookmark toolbar in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, bookmarks

I'd like to have a shortcut key that shows/hides the bookmark toolbar (not the sidebar).
(Yes, I've got the idea from Chrome). I've been searching for a solution to this particular itch, but found none. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Hide BookmarksBar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-bookmarksbar/) extension

Comment: +1 because I have tested this add-on version `3.3.1-signed.1-signed` and it works for Firefox 46.x (only tested in Linux, untested in Windows).

Comment: The default hotkey is set to `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`L` but some users i.e. Linux users might disagree because this combination key is used for locking current session. In such case, change the combination key to something like `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`B`.

Comment: This used to be a great option. However, with the phasing out of "legacy" extensions, it no longer works, and I feel it's unlikely to be updated as a WebExtension. Please vote for [this Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1328637) on Bugzilla.

Answer (score 16):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>

Open "**V**iew" menu > **T**oolbars > **B**ookmarks Toolbar

Comment: For the German Fx: Alt+A+Y+L

Comment: couldn't get it to work. should i press v+t+b together or one after the other?

Comment: oops, got it. you mean, use the menu shortcuts, right? i knew that, but not only i have to type 4 buttons, i'd need the menu to be there in the first place. i usually turn them off...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Keyconfig add-on](http://mozilla.dorando.at/keyconfig.xpi) and [this](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=3201061#p3201061) script:

```
var toolbar = document.getElementById("PersonalToolbar");
toolbar.collapsed = !toolbar.collapsed;
document.persist(toolbar.id, "collapsed");
```

After installing Keyconfig, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to bring up the key binding interface. Create a new shortcut using the code above, and bind it to any key combination you want. Tested and working in Firefox 3.5.5.

Comment: No longer an option with mainstream versions of Firefox; if you wanted to keep using Keyconfig (or [this updated version](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dorando-keyconfig/)) you would need the [ESR release](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/) or [a third-party fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_Moon_(web_browser)) of Firefox. Even ESR will drop support for the "legacy" extensions later this year. A better long-term solution is to just get the keyboard shortcut added to Firefox itself; see comments above for the relevant Bugzilla bug.