# Is it possible to bind a key combination to a bookmark in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

*[Shortcut key for bookmark toolbar in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/77206/)* instructs how to toggle the keyboard, so I started there, but I couldn't figure how to trigger a bookmark.

I have a bookmarklet I'd like to be able to trigger keyboardwise. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way of assigning a hotkey like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to a bookmark(let) directly in Firefox. However, you have a built-in function in Firefox to assign a key sequence like "abc" to a bookmark.

Combine this with the shortcut for accessing the address bar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) and you're good to go.

Bring up the properties of the bookmark as described in *[Firefox's Bookmark Manager](http://mozilla.gunnars.net/firefox_bookmarks_tutorial.html#Bookmark_Manager)* and enter the sequence in the keyword field (e.g. abc, or in this example: Help).

[image: Screenshot of Firefox bookmark properties]

Now in order to get to your bookmarklet, do this:

1. Press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
2. Enter your sequence
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Done

It is a two-step shortcut, but it should do the trick without extensions or adding additional software to your system.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fit your needs, but AutoHotkey is an application to make shortcuts for everything. It's extremely powerful and flexible, and this link might be what you're looking for: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic42488.html

So instead of navigating to the website they give you, you could navigate to the bookmark.

Hope that helps.

AutoHotkey download page: http://www.autohotkey.com/download/