# How to show/hide the Bookmarks Toolbar in Firefox using a sane key shortcut?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to show/hide the bookmark toolbar in Firefox. The only way to do this at the moment is via <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>. Now, that's a lot of buttons to press for something I'd like to do all the time. Is there a way to automate this process by using any sane combination (two buttons)?

Comment: <ctrl>+<b> doesn't work for you?

Comment: @DavidPostill No, I don't want to show/hide the *bookmarks sidebar*, I want to show/hide the *bookmarks toolbar*.

Comment: OK. I've edited the question to make that clear.

Comment: You could probably use something like [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) to do what you want.

Comment: [This older post](http://superuser.com/q/77206/109256) has most upvoted answer that suggested to use "Hide BookmarksBar" extension.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the "menu bar" still existed, that's where all the main options are. Can't show hide from the new hamburger menu dropdown it firefox 58 it seems.

Comment: I was looking for the same answer but `Alt + V + T + B` mentioned in the question is good enough for me, I'll take it.

Comment: The Firefox team has decided to work on this and will implement it in Firefox 83 (likely). The task assignee wrote that "The shortcut will be Ctrl+Shift+B on Linux and Windows. And Cmd+Shift+B on macOS." -> https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1328637

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + B` is as of Firefox release 84.0

Comment: @sagarr This is the correct answer, they finally addressed this! Can you please make your comment an answer so that I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: @Aventinus not enough reputation :( but you can add answer to your questions.

Comment: [Fixed in Firefox 84](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1328637). See my update below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Firefox release 84.0 you can show/hide the bookmarks toolbar using `Ctrl + Shift + B`.

Thank you @sagarr for letting me know in the comments (@sagarr did not have enough reputation to answer himself).

Answer (score 11):

**Update**: Fixed in Firefox 84 (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1328637).

The shortcut should be <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd><modifier></kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> on all three platforms now, where <kbd><modifier></kbd> is either Control or ⌘, depending on the OS.

Now, you open the "Library" with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd><modifier></kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (I like the mnemonic "Organizer"), which changed the long-standing shortcut on some platforms and [didn't make everyone happy](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1328637#c71). I for one am thrilled by the change, *because* I use all three OSes regularly, and having consistency is helpful.

---

As you know there is no shortcut for this like you would have in Chrome or Opera, and as of this writing (mid-2019) there are no obvious, straightforward ways of customizing Firefox's keyboard shortcuts anymore without doing something like… coding.

There are, as you might be aware, *other* options like macOS's Keyboard prefpane, AutoHotkey on Windows, and [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) on Linux, but I don't know if writing a script just to click a menu item qualifies as "sane" anymore.

The [Hide BookmarksBar extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-bookmarksbar/) *used* to be a pretty okay option, and might still be if you are fine with running <strike>one of the [ESR releases](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2017/10/03/legacy-add-on-support-on-firefox-esr/) or</strike> (***Update**: ESR dropped support for "legacy" addons in August 2018)* a [third-party fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_Moon_(web_browser)) of Firefox that still supports "legacy" extensions.

However, as noted in [that other SU post](http://superuser.com/q/77206/109256), the "Hide BookmarksBar" extension no longer works in current mainstream versions of Firefox. Given the present limitations of the WebExtension API, it seems unlikely at the moment that the HideBookmarksBar extension could be updated to work again as a WebExtension. [This fork](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/dorando-keyconfig/) of [dorando's original keyconfig](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994) (which still works with Thunderbird as of this writing) might've also been able to do the job, before mainstream Firefox dropped support for non-WebExtension addons. So, same situation.

For these reasons, I would encourage you to voice your support and/or vote for [Firefox bug #1328637](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1328637) ("Personal toolbar lacks a keyboard shortcut to show/hide the bar") on Mozilla's bug tracker.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, and you are right. I will do just that. I'm not marking your answer as the correct one however in the unlikely scenario where a proper solution becomes available.

Comment: Understood, no worries. This is more like a long comment than a real answer anyway. Let's cross our fingers for the shortcut to be implemented in Firefox itself, then we can quit with all these workarounds. `:)`

Answer (score 9):

OSX specific:

1. go to `System Preferences` -> `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts`
2. set an `App Shortcut`
   [image]

Comment: I had tried this and quickly given up on it, because it seemed like it wasn't working half the time. I run an old version of macOS, though, and later versions could've fixed whatever it was? What I _did_ discover in the meantime is that if you click (manually, with the mouse) _View_ → _Toolbars_ → _Bookmarks Toolbar_ **once**, after you initially open Firefox, the hotkey set in the macOS prefpane seems to work for the rest of your browsing session, which is annoying, but not _too_ annoying. It's probably a Firefox bug, because this method usually works reliably for "native" Mac applications.

Comment: Hmm, this interesting. For me, using the Dvorak-Qwerty⌘ keyboard layout, it works a bit weirdly (Firefox ignores the Qwerty⌘ part of that) but sort of works.

Comment: For non-english versions of FF: use localized name of menu entry. For example in Russian FF you can find it in path like: _Вид_ → _Панели инструментов_ → _Панель закладок_, so you should use _Панель закладок_ in shortcut settings. Btw still the same behaviour in MacOS 10.14.6 + FF 71.0, so use @TheDudeAbides trick to make things work.

Answer (score 1):

Using [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html) and [wmctrl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl), under unix:

```
wmctrl -xa Firefox && xdotool key F2 alt+v t Down KP_Enter
```

This will toggle the Firefox bookmark toolbar.

Or to force it:

```
wmctrl -xa Firefox && xdotool key F2 alt+v t b
```

We can link this command to a keyboard shortcut, or use in scripts.

Comment: Thanks!  This works for me without the `F2`.  Was that perhaps a copy-and-paste error from xdotool(1)?